# Alternative to nested promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a function that gets a presigned s3 url (call 1) and does a put to s3. The only way I'm able to figure it out in my head is using a nested promise which I understand to be an anti-pattern.

Writing it out in js/pseudocode

```
uploadfile(file){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(get-presigned-s3url).then((url) =>{ return axios.put(file)}
  })
}

let filePromises = files.forEach(file => uploadfile(file));
promises.all((filePromises) => notifyUpload(filePromises));
```

I need to return a promise from the uploadfile function to wait for all the promises to resolve. What's the right way to handle this scenario?

Comment: what are you doing with `url` from the promise result of `axios.get()`?

Comment: hint: what does `axios.put` return?

Comment: you realise `uploadfile` returns a Promise that never resolves ... just `return axios.get(.....` no need to wrap a function that returns a Promise in a promise constructor

Comment: also ... `array.forEach` returns `undefined` .... you want `array.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `axios.get` returns a Promise already, you don't need to construct another one around it with `new Promise`.

`files.forEach` won't work, because `forEach` returns `undefined`. Use `.map` instead, so you have an array of Promises.

```
const uploadFile = file => axios.get(url)
    .then((url) => { return axios.put(file); });
```

```
Promise.all(
  files.map(uploadFile)
)
  .then(notifyUpload)
  .catch(handleErrors);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was extremely helpful.

(Been struggling somewhat with wrapping my head around promises!)